# Docker Quickstart Terminal nano: unrecognized option `--login'

Tags: macos, docker

When starting Docker Quickstart Terminal on `macos el capitan` I get this error:

```
bash --login '/Applications/Docker/Docker Quickstart Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh'
Password:
nano: unrecognized option `--login'
Usage: nano [OPTIONS] [[+LINE,COLUMN] FILE]...

Option      GNU long option     Meaning
 -h, -?     --help          Show this message
 +LINE,COLUMN               Start at line LINE, column COLUMN
 -A     --smarthome     Enable smart home key
 -B     --backup        Save backups of existing files
```

and cannot start docker. Anyone had this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I edited the command to be `sh` instead of `bash` and now it works.

```
sh --login '/Applications/Docker/Docker Quickstart Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh'
```

also you should not have any aliases with names like `bash`